# Python execute a function in parallel in loop

Tags: python, multithreading

I tried to improve the execution time of a script which import datas from CSV into Graphite/Go-Carbon DB time series.

this is the loop which parse all zipfiles and read them in function (execute_run) :
It tried this code but i got an error:

```
    for idx4, Lst_f in enumerate(full_csvfile_paths):
       if lst_metrics in Lst_f:
          zip_file = Lst_f
          with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file) as zipobj:
             print("Using ZipFile:",zipobj.filename)
             #execute_run(zipobj.filename, confcsv_path, storage_type, serial)
             output = subprocess.run(execute_run(zipobj.filename, confcsv_path, storage_type, serial),stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
             print ("Return code: %i" % output.returncode)
             print ("Output data: %s" % output.stdout)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./02-pickle-client.py", line 451, in <module>
    main()
  File "./02-pickle-client.py", line 361, in main
    output = subprocess.run(execute_run(zipobj.filename, confcsv_path, storage_type, serial),stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 423, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1240, in _execute_child
    args = list(args)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Is there a way to execute **X times** the function :"**execute_run**" and control the correct running.

Many thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be that the parallel processes is not set up to handle iterables correctly. Instead of `subprocess.run`, I would recommend using
`multiprocessing.pool` or `multiprocessing.starmap` as specified [in these docs.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=pool#module-multiprocessing.pool)

This could look something like this:

```
    import multiprocessing as mp

    # Step 1: Use multiprocessing.Pool() and specify number of cores to use (here I use 4).
    pool = mp.Pool(4)

    # Step 2: Use pool.starmap which takes a multiple iterable arguments
    results = pool.starmap(My_Function, [(variable1,variable2,variable3) for i in data])
    
    # Step 3: Don't forget to close
    pool.close()
```

Comment: Hi C.L, thank you for your answer, i used the multiprocessing, but at the beginning, i got the following errors:   Process ForkPoolWorker-1:
Process ForkPoolWorker-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
....
then after the first Zip, the script hangs
Many thanks for help

Comment: I would try to first write the program as a for loop without parallel processing. When you successfully can perform 2-3 loops of your execute_run function on different zip objects, then simply put your full iterable in the pool.starmap function (where I have written "data" above). Also, multiprocessing does not work well in some IDEs (e.g., spyder), so I would recommend using PyCharm or another IDE that can simply implement multiprocessing.

Comment: It's ok, i found the issue :)